# Syntax differences in property access expressions

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)

Let's consider I have an object:

```
var o = { x:1, y:2 };
```

What is the difference when I access a property like this:

```
o.x
```

Compared to this:

```
o["x"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are called [Member Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators), and there is a good bit of information on them in that link.

The only real differences are that the bracket notation allows you to disobey variable naming rules and do things like:

```
o["3213adascas        #@%!"] = 5;
```

While the following is obviously a syntax error:

```
o.3213adascas        #@%! = 5;
```

Also since bracket notation takes in a string you can use variables with it:

```
var o = { x:1, y:2 };
var member = 'y';
console.log(o[member]); // Outputs 2
```

Answer (score 2):

`o.x` is effectively just syntactic sugar for `o["x"]`. They do the same thing. However, the square bracket notation allows you for example to use the value of a variable as the property name to access:

```
var someString = "x";
o[someString];
```

As well as this, if the property name is not a valid identifier, the square bracket notation must be used:

```
var myObj = {
    "space property": 1
};
myObj["space property"];
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference - exactly the same thing ... but does enable keys with spaces / obscure characters :

```
o['something here'] = "test";
```

will work for example, but this wont :

```
o.something here = "test";
```

Answer (score 2):

The square bracket notation has an advantage. You can set properties dynamically.

> **From [JavaScript Garden](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#object.general)**
>
> ```js
> var foo = {name: 'Kitten'}
> foo.name; // kitten
> foo['name']; // kitten
>
> var get = 'name';
> foo[get]; // kitten
>
> foo.1234; // SyntaxError
> foo['1234']; // works
> ```
>
> Both notations are identical in their workings, with the only difference being that the  square bracket
>   notation allows for dynamic setting of properties, as well as the use
>   of property names that would otherwise lead to a syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

These two do exactly the same thing. However, bracket notation (`o["x"]`) allows you to do two things that you cannot do with dot notation (`o.x`):

1. Access a property with an arbitrary string. For example, `o["function"]` and `o["432 %^$ ==="]` are valid syntax, but `o.function` is not valid because `function` is a keyword, and `o.432 %^$ ===` is not valid because it constitutes a syntax error.
2. Set a dynamic property of an object. You can do `var str = "prop";` and access `o[str]` with bracket notation.